# Restrict Height of Google Adsense Ads

Tags: html, css

We have a site that has a responsive google ad on top of the content. On desktop it shows a long horisontal rectangle ad which is perfect.

On mobile it shows a large rectangle which is not good as it takes most of the screen. Is there any way to restrict the container of the ad for example to max height of 250px. That way the ad will not be large rectangle on mobile?

Thanks

Comment: You can use [max-height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-height).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Use a media query to test for smaller devices

### then add a max height to your element

Replace the [.google-addword-class] below with the class that google adwords uses.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    [.google-addword-class] {
        max-height: 200px !important;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `max-height:` attribute should suffice I believe. You can [read](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_max-height.asp) more about it.